# Ways to escape single quotes in SQL 'LIKE' command

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, mysql, oracle10g

What are the various ways to ESCAPE single quotes(') in the SQL `LIKE` command?

One way is to put two single quotes whenever you have to escape a single quote.

Can you people suggest something?

Databases: [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) and Oracle 10g

Answer (score 19):

You already have the answer. You have to use two single quotes:

```
select * from table where field like '%''something''%'
```

Answer (score 3):

Two single quotes is the best solution.

Alternatively, you can use a `CHAR(39)` to represent a single quote character.

```
UPDATE Employee SET LastName = 'O' +  CHAR(39) + 'Brien' 
WHERE ID=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to bind the parameter with ADO or ADO.NET.

Like (example in C# with ADO.NET):

```
SqlCommand x = new SqlCommand(sqlConnection, @"select * from table where col like '%'+@para1+'%'");
x.parameters.add(new SqlParameter("@para1",sqltype.varchar,100)).value = "this is a' test";
```

In [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005) you escape a single quote (') with a double single quote ('') if you do not want to bind:

```
select * from table where col like '%this is a'' test%'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to search the value ***Allen O'Dea*** following is the query.

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [COLUMN] LIKE '%Allen O''Dea%'
```

This query works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the "Q-quote" method:

```
select * from mytable where text like q'#%Here's some text%#';
```

This is available since Oracle 10.2.

I used a '#' character as the quote delimiter, but you can use pretty much any character that won't appear in the string (there are a few exceptions, such as the space character).

In a simple example like that above I probably wouldn't do this. I'd just double up the single quotes, but it does come in handy when building large dynamic SQL statements that include lots of string literals.

Comment: Isn't this only works in PL/SQL block ? I guess we cannot use this in plain SQL.